# Get result LIKE from 2 column codeingiter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a search query to search in 3 columns:

```
WHERE t.name LIKE ? 
   OR t.keywords LIKE ? 
   OR t.version LIKE ?
```

When I search for `like "program"`, I get result also if I search for "2.2" I got results.

How can I search with each other like this `t.name + t.version` = `"program 2.2"` and get results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to try (or like)

as example

```
   $this->db->select('*')->from('my_table')
        ->group_start()
                ->where('a', 'a')
                ->or_group_start()
                        ->where('b', 'b')
                        ->where('c', 'c')
                ->group_end()
        ->group_end()
        ->where('d', 'd')->get();
```

the query will look like this

```
SELECT * FROM (`my_table`) WHERE ( `a` = 'a' OR ( `b` = 'b' AND `c` = 'c' ) ) AND `d` = 'd'
```

this functionality allows you to search in more than one column

Answer (score 1):

Here some example suggestions:

[https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-73265.html](http://Examples)

Comment: its just about or_like its not helpful ineed LIKE from 2 column not 1